# Why Bootstrap carousel caption visible in development but not production?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, display

I'm working on a portfolio website, for which I display screenshots in a Bootstrap Carousel.

In React Development Server Captions render and operate correctly:

```
npm run start
```

[Development Server Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3v8D.png)

Production Build, cations are in HTML, but don't visibly render:

```
npm run build
serve -s build
```

[Production Server Brower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCg3L.png)

```
<Carousel key= {'in-depth'+projectIndex}  activeIndex={pageIndex} onSelect={(i,e)=>{setPageIndex(i); console.log('select-called'); forceUpdate();}} className='col-lg-8 col-md-10' style={{margin: '1.0rem auto',}}>
            {projects[projectIndex].pages.map((page,i) => 
                <Carousel.Item key={projects[projectIndex].pages[i].target+i+projects[projectIndex].title} interval={5000} style={{maxHeight: '75vh', overflowY: page.type == 'vertical-scroll' ? 'scroll' : 'hidden'}} class={i==0 ? 'active' : ''}>
                {page.type == 'video' ?
                <Player playing src={conceptVersion}  height='420' width='720' controls={true} style={{margin: '0 auto', textAlign: 'center'}} className='project-image'/>
                : <img  className="d-block w-100 project-image" src={projects[projectIndex].pages[i].image} alt={projects[projectIndex].pages[i].target} />}
                    <h3 className='carousel-title' >{projects[projectIndex].title}</h3>
                    {page.type == 'vertical-scroll' ? <div></div>
                    : <div id='describe-box' className='carousel-description-box' style={{}}>
                        <p className='carousel-description' >{projects[projectIndex].pages[i].description}</p>
                    </div>}
                </Carousel.Item>)}
        </Carousel>
```

Source Code: https://github.com/ethanjohnsrud/portfolio/blob/main/src/Projects/Projects.jsx

Live Website: https://5fd8f2548eaa992466b41f48--ethan-johnsrud-portfolio.netlify.app/

Any idea why the difference, and how might I fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caused by `opacity: 1%;` --> 0% fully transparent. In Projects.css: .carousel-description block

Comment: Thanks so much this was driving my crazy.  It's listed as 90% in CSS, so I'll have to track down where it changed.